# What happens if you take the watch in The Walking Dead Game Season 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

What happens if you take the watch in The Walking Dead Game Season 2?

Answer (score 2):

If you picked up the gold watch from the cabin in In Seaseon 2 Episode 2 "All That Remains", you will have the option in Episode 3, "[A House Divided](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/A_House_Divided)", to either give it to Nick when he realises he didn't have it, or keep hold of it.